# Display results from a hash (similar to map without brackets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to format the result hash from a query which looks like this:

`notations = NotationItem.joins(:user).select(:name,:notation).where("movie_id = ?",self.id)`

Note : NotationItem is the Many to Many table from the relationship between User and Movie

:name comes from User table, :notation from NotationItem

I could use...

```
notations.map {|n| "#{n.name}: #{n.notation}"}
```

but the square bracket output format is not usable for me.

from that moment i thought i could use

```
notations.each do |key, value|
        "#{key}: #{value}"
    end
```

but it seems that my hash is not built the right way.

Sorry i ask for such basic needs...

Comment: why so *the square bracket syntax is not usable for me.* ? What is the problem with it ?

Comment: I've no problem with bracket syntax, my bad, i wanted to say square brackets output format like in ["name1: notation1", "name2: notation2"]

Comment: Okay,, Then I can see it is being produced by `notations.map {|n| "#{n.name}: #{n.notation}"}`.. Is not it ?

Comment: My bad, i was simply displaying the array (reason for [] ouput). .join method helped me achieve the correct output (without brackets) thk you

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Just show us the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: @Agis OP said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149927/display-results-from-a-hash-similar-to-map-without-brackets#comment33611978_22150181)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
notations.map do |n|
  "#{n.name}: #{n.notation}"
end.join(', ') # => "name1: notation1, name2: notation2"
```

Comment: reason? Why you are asking to use `do..end`..?

Comment: sorry, i wanted to say square brackets output format like in ["name1: notation1", "name2: notation2"]

Comment: @Tabascow What about now? You can use `#join` to make the array a string.

Comment: I sure did and it solved it. I was indeed displaying the array in raw format (displaying brackets in that case). Using .join helped me display the right ouput. THk you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to print the result. Doing a `.map` on a Hash will give you an Array, not a String. You probably want something like this:

```
hash = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}

p hash.map { |key, value| "#{key}: #{value}" }.join(", ")
# => "key1: value1, key2: value2"
```

You can replace the `{ .. }` by `do .. end` if you want.

Comment: That is correct, it sounds like i forgot that the result of a map was an array and i simply skip the .join method afterwards. Thk you so much for bringing yours eyes on it